# Color overlay above form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have created this form: https://radlvoo.de/jans-testplatz/

But I want to have an overlay above the whole form. I already have googled and tried to use this CSS styling:

```css
z-index: 500;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
overflow: auto;
```

```html
<div id="rahmenhöhenRechnerOverlay" style="z-index: 500;width: 100%;height: 100%;top: 0;left: 0;right: 0;bottom: 0;/* background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); */overflow: auto;">
  <form class="filterform form-inline">
    <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">FAHRRADTYP</label><br>
      <select id="fahrradtypHöhenrechner" class="form-control" name="typ"><option value="">Bitte wählen…</option><option value="trekkingrad">TREKKINGRAD</option><option value="cityrad">CITYRAD</option><option value="mountainbike hardtail">MOUNTAINBIKE HARDTAIL</option><option value="mointainbike fully">MOUNTAINBIKE FULLY</option><option value="crossrad">CROSSRAD</option><option value="rennrad">RENNRAD</option></select>
      <p
        class="empty"></p>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">GESCHLECHT</label><br>
      <select id="geschlechtHöhenrechner" class="form-control" name="geschlecht"><option value="">Bitte wählen…</option><option value="damen">DAMEN</option><option value="herren">HERREN</option></select>
      <p class="empty"></p>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">FAHRSTYLE</label><br>
      <input name="fahrstyle" type="radio" value="sportlich"> Sportlich orientiert<br>
      <input name="fahrstyle" type="radio" value="touren"> Touren orientiert
      <p class="empty"></p>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">SCHRITTHÖHE</label><br>
      <input id="schritthöheInput" min="0" name="schritthöhe" type="number">
      <p class="empty"></p>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-block" style="margin-top: 20px;"><button style="display: inline-block; padding: 6px 12px; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 1.42857143; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: middle; -ms-touch-action: manipulation; touch-action: manipulation; cursor: pointer; -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none; background-image: none; border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 4px; color: #ffffff; background-color: #26aef2; border-color: #26aef2;"
        type="button">Rahmenhöhe berechnen</button></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

But sadly it isn't working... How can I create an overlay which goes from the top of the form till the bottom of the form and also above the form itselfs?

Kind regards

Comment: Paste your html code in too.

Comment: If you provide more information, you'll probably get better answers. For starters: the HTML for your overlay, and the HTML/CSS for your form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an overlay layer to need to add **position:absolute**. And your container should be **position: relative**. For example:

```
  .container {
    position: relative;
  }
  .child {
    z-index: 500;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample CSS you've shown is a little out of context, but assuming that's for the overlay, then you need to also make it `position: absolute`. You also need to set the `form` to `position: relative`, something like this:

```css
form {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 500;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input /><br />
  <input /><br />
  <button type="button">Submit</button>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</form>
```

Note that `width` and `height` are irrelevant in this case as you're specifying `top`, `left` etc.